# Docker secrets in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-secrets

I have encountered problems with usage of docker secrets in docker-compose. Here is my yml:

```
version: '3.6'

secrets:
  aws_bucket_name:
    file: ./secrets/aws_bucket_name.txt

services:
  my-service-name:
    image: my-service-name
    secrets:
      - aws_bucket_name
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
    volumes:
      - ./:/my-service-name
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
      - 9229:9229
    environment:
      AUTH_BASICAUTH_ENABLED: "true"
      NODE_ENV: "development"
```

So, If I understand it correctly I should have aws_bucket_name.txt in my project in secrets folder, that is truth.

I'm trying to load data from this file through aws_bucket_name.

When I build docker-compose I get this error:

ERROR: for iothubtelemetryadapter_my-service-name_1  Cannot create container for service my-service-name: invalid mount config for type "bind": invalid mount path: 'C:/Users/anton.smatanik/Documents/project_name/secrets/aws_bucket_name.txt' mount path must be absolute

Here is my project structure:

[image]

Comment: can you show your folder structure ?

Comment: I just edited a question and added a project structure image

Comment: whats the permission of bucket file ? maybe docker cant read it ?

Comment: the permissions are 777 for a file so it should be OK

Comment: See https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4829 `Question: Are docker-compose secrets supported on Windows Containers?`

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand, you're just declaring your secret but not using it as a value.

Try to input your secret as a value of the actual variable that you want to hide.

Ex:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
 my-service:
  image: my-image
  secrets: secret-db-string
  environment:
  - db_connection_string=secret-db-string
secrets:
 secret-db-string:
  file: ./path/to/secret/file
```